# Can't use multiple reducers with combineReducers, getting an unknown property warning on state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have my store set up as follows:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login: loginReducer,
    counter: counterReducer
});

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer
});
```

The login reducer/slice looks as follows:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const loginSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'login',
    initialState: {
        isLoggedIn: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        login: (state) => {
            state.isLoggedIn = true;
        },
        logout: (state) => {
        state.isLoggedIn = false;
        },
    },
});

export const { login, logout } = loginSlice.actions;

export default loginSlice.reducer;
```

The counter reducer/slice looks as follows:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'counter',
    initialState: {
        counterValue: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        increment: (state) => {
            state.counterValue += 1;
        },
        decrement: (state) => {
            state.counterValue -= 1;
        },
        incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
            state.counterValue += action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

The problem now is that I can't access the values from these two reducers this way, which should be the right way (also according to the Redux Devtools):

```
const counterValue = useSelector((state) => state.counter.counterValue);
const counterValue = useSelector((state) => state.login.isLoggedIn);
```

Doing something like this:

```
const counterValue = useSelector((state) => state.counterValue);
const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.login.isLoggedIn);
```

... returns `undefined`, but trying to do `state.counter.counterValue` or `state.login.isLoggedIn` gives me the error of unknown property on `state`.

I get an error saying `Property 'counter' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`. I'm using Typescript, and maybe the unknown type of state is the issue, but not sure and no idea how to fix that if that's the problem. Why are the properties given in the `combineReducers` call unknown on the `state` object when trying to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using TypeScript, you should consider following the redux recommendations and [create typed RootState and store hooks](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript).

As a part of your store setup:

```
const store = configureStore(...)

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
type DispatchFunc = () => AppDispatch
export const useAppDispatch: DispatchFunc = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

`RootState` will be a type that is inferred from the state defined for each slice. In your example, `state.login` and `state.counter`. `useAppSelector` is then a type safe and convenient way of using `useSelector((state: RootState) => ...)`, allowing:

```
const counterValue = useAppSelector(state => state.counter.counterValue);
const isLoggedIn = useAppSelector(state => state.login.isLoggedIn);
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the useSelector issue. However when trying to call the useAppDispatch I get an error for this: `useAppDispatch(increment());`

Gives me the following error: `Calling this redux#ActionCreator will return a PayloadAction of type T with a payload of undefined` and `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`

Comment: Are you sure that error is from dispatching increment() and not incrementByAmount()? Or dispatching increment WITH a payload?  When your actions do have payloads, you should specify the payload type  like this: `incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>)`

Comment: Yes it really happens when calling `increment()`. I have changed this line: `type DispatchFunc = () => AppDispatch;` to this: `type DispatchFunc = (action: PayloadAction) => AppDispatch;`. This removes the error.

Comment: I solved the issue following the guide from the Redux docs shared by Chris. I now have another issue, but that needs a new question as it's unrelated to this topic. Thanks guys!